# Products RSS feed Google Integration with Sitefinity CMS

Tags: rss, sitefinity

Need to implement an RSS feed to connect to Google from Sitefinity to publish all of the products listed on the site under the e-commerce section.

Couple of questions,

1.Looking at alternative publishing options, I can't select products as content. (Blogs, News, etc are available) is there a way to make products available?

2.Is this functionality available out of the box or will I need to write custom code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not available out of the box. 
What you need to do is create a custom widget and in it iterate through all products and output the correct format the google expects.